# Springbook 2.0 interceptor forward to controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am building a small application in which I am trying to manage user login session.

My question is, is it possible to forward the http request from `HandlerInterceptor.preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)` method to controller

Something like this..

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    request.getRequestDispatcher("someController").forward(request, response);

    return true;

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The request already has a controller mapped at this point. `return true` to process the request as normal and `false` to cancel.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to understand whether I can use interceptor to define the follow of the system. trying to understand whether a httprequest can be forwarded to any controller from interceptor.